# How to personalize one arrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

im my project i need to show the same arrayList in two differents activities. In MainActivity i need to show only items who have isConsumido atribute = false. In TelaCadastrados activity i need to show the entire arrayList. How i do that?

```
package com.example.breno.seenme;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemCultural> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(this.getItem(position).isConsumido()){
        // I Think the code to hide elements with isConsumido = true
    }else{

    }
    return v;
}
}
```

In my MainActivity adapter instance.

```
        CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CustomAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY);
```

How this customAdapter will recognize my List ?

My Custon Adapter:

```
package com.example.breno.seenme;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> {

public static final int VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY = 124; // or some random int.
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_TELACADAS = 125; // or some random int.

private int viewType;
List<ItemCultural> lista;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int viewType) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.viewType = viewType;
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemCultural> items, int viewType) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.viewType = viewType;
    this.lista = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY) {
        // DO your logic for mainActivity version of the list.
        // I Think the code to hide elements with isConsumido = true
        if (!lista.get(position).isConsumido()) {
            //showThisView(v);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TELACADAS) {
        // DO your logic for Telacadas version of the list
    } else {
        // UNSUPPORTED VIEW TYPE.
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: You could return a really small and narrow view in getView for items you want to hide, but I wouldn't do it that way. If this attribute is dynamic and changing, then I would use a CursorAdapter and  ContentProvider so that I could put the exclusion logic in the query. Otherwise I might just filter the arraylist before adding the arraylist to the array adapter. You can do this by manually checking each item inside a for loop or use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While constructing the adapter, pass which type of View you want to render, the `MainActivity` version of the list or the `TelaCadastradosActivity` version of the list.

So you modify your adapter to this

```
package com.example.breno.seenme;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> {

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY = 124; // or some random int.
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_TELACADAS = 125; // or some random int.

    private int viewType;
    List<ItemCultural> lista;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int resource;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int viewType) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.viewType = viewType;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemCultural> items, int viewType) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.viewType = viewType;
        this.lista = items;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY) {
            // DO your logic for mainActivity version of the list.
            // I Think the code to hide elements with isConsumido = true
            if (!lista.get(position).isConsumido()) {
                //showThisView(v);
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((TextView)v).setText(lista.get(position).toString());
            }
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TELACADAS) {
            // DO your logic for Telacadas version of the list
        } else {
            // UNSUPPORTED VIEW TYPE.
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

And in your `MainActivity` you instantiate your adapter like this

```
final CustomAdapter arrayAdapterOrdenado = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais(). CustomAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY);
```

For TelaCadasActivity you pass in the TelaCadas view type

```
final CustomAdapter arrayAdapterOrdenado = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais(). CustomAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_TELACADAS);
```

Comment: @BrenoHenrique post the at the bottom of your question by editing your question and not as an answer

Comment: so where i need to call getView method? Thanks!

Comment: you don't have to call the `getView()` method, the adapter will do it for you, just set the listview's adapter as the adapter you instantiated

Comment: `if (!lista.get(position).isConsumido()) {
            //showThisView(v);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }` I thought you needed to show view if isConsumido == false, but you are doing it reverse

Comment: i fixed that, but im not passing my ItemCultural list anywhere like your code exemples. Right? So my adapters are empty.

Comment: yes you need to pass in data, I still don't know where the variable `lista` is coming from EDIT: oh nvm just saw your edited code you added it in the 2nd constructor

Comment: which constructor i need to use? and in 2nd constructor, int resource is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Comment: yes the constructor that takes in the list, because you need to show items, and a layout like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` will do if you only want to show text, and be sure to override toString() function in `ItemCultural`

Comment: can you tell me how i need to instantiate my MainActivity adapter? My List is regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais() .

Comment: project is on github [link](https://github.com/brenosc2/seen.me) , the toString method is already implemented.

Comment: `final ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> arrayAdapterOrdenado = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais());
` that is correct just make sure that  `.getListaDeItensCulturais()` is returning non empty list

Comment: But that code dont instantiate one CustomAdapter, but one ArrayAdapter. Im so confused :/

Comment: @BrenoHenrique oops, just change that to `final CustomAdapter<ItemCultural> arrayAdapterOrdenado = new CustomAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais(). CustomAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY);`

Comment: Don't works, in CustomAdapter<ItemCultural> android studio says "Type ... does not have type parameters" and in new CustomAdapter<> android studio says "Diamond operator is not applicable for non-parametrized types".

Comment: umm.. just remove that `final CustomAdapter arrayAdapterOrdenado = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais(). CustomAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_MAINACTIVITY);`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.breno.seenme.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:38)

Comment: I don't need to change anything in someone xml file?

Comment: ofcourse you need to inflate the layout >.> , wait let me edit the answer

Comment: If i comment the two lines who manipulates v element, app crashes in java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)

Comment: @BrenoHenrique check the edited code, I added inflating the layout resource in it

Comment: wow man, this helped me alot! Works pretty fine, but when one item is added to List with isConsumido = false, the mainActivity adapter shows one blank space, its not completely invisible.Is there any way to fix this? Thank you bro!!!

Comment: @BrenoHenrique could be that Nome is empty string i.e `nome = ""`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options. In your MainActivity, you could pass your adapter a copy of your data with only the isConsumido == false entries. Alternatively, you could add some logic to your adapter to skip over the items where isConsumido == true. You would have to update the getCount() and getView() methods to take into account the items to skip over.

It's the usual trade off of memory (more memory in the first solution) versus complexity (the 2nd solution is more complex, but more memory efficient as it uses a single list).